# Photo grid/collage with custom layouts and exporting for Windows

Tags: windows, photography, collage

I'm looking for a Windows (desktop) software to place several pictures into a single one and it has to export the final **high resolution** result image to JPEG (at least).

I would like also the application to let me choose from **different customizable layouts** (such as 3 pictures, 4, 5, etc. in different combinations of width/height) and allow to crop an input picture or zoom it to make it fit into the selected layout cell.

I've found [Snap Photo Collage](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/snap-photo-collage/9wzdncrdf3m8) on the Microsoft Store, but I would like something for Win32.

Answer (score -1):

With [Irfan View](https://www.irfanview.com) (3MB)you can crop, cut, convert, edit (edit exif), add overlay, Batch conversion, lossless rotation, Unicode support, Multi language support, 32 and 64 bit version.
This Software is available as Windows App or as Installer or USB Version. 
You can put our Images in any position into an empty new Picture, before you can every Image customizing in our format that you are need to have.
And this tool provides many plug ins for different file formats.

The automatically collage feature doesn't merge multiple images into one　but you can create a blank image and on there you can put manually all your Images as you want and save them in any format that you will have.

Comment: Thanks, but does it have the layout/collage feature to merge multiple images into one? I don't think so.

Comment: @Native2904: When replying to improvement suggestions, please edit your answer, thanks!